# how to transpose dataframe in shiny with custom column names

Tags: r, shiny

I have following dataframe in shiny which looks something like this. I am using `renderDataTable` to display this in shiny

```
  QC1     QC2     QC3
   12      23      34
```

I want it to be displayed like this in a tabular format

```
  Parameters        Resources
     QC1               12
     QC2               23
     QC3               32
```

I am using transpose to change it. but it is displaying only values.

Comment: You need to melt it (see `reshape2` package) in your server logic and render a table from that data frame. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose will return you a matrix.

You will need to convert it into a data frame again.

```
data.frame(Parameters = rownames(t(df)), Resources = t(df))
```

Comment: I still get `X1` as a column name instead of resources

Answer (score 1):

I think nowadays this can be done using `tidyr` the easiest:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% gather(Parameters, Resources)
```